# A question on the domain of a non-commutative Radon-Nikodym derivative

Tags: oa.operator-algebras

Let $\omega$ be a state on a $C^*$-algebra $\mathfrak{A}$ and $\pi_\omega:\mathfrak{A}\rightarrow B(\mathcal{H}_\omega)$ its GNS representation. Suppose in addition that $\omega$ has central support, so that the GNS vector $\xi_\omega$ is cyclic and separating for the von Neumann algebra
$\pi_\omega(\mathfrak{A})''$ (the double commutant of $\pi_\omega(\mathfrak{A})$ ). This allows us to consider the modular flow on $\pi_\omega(\mathfrak{A})''$ provided by the Tomita-Takesaki theory.
$$$$ Let now $\varphi$ be another state on $\mathfrak{A}$,
such that its GNS representation $\pi_\varphi$ is unitarily equivalent to $\pi_\omega$. By a standard application of
the Tomita-Takesaki theory, one can readily see that there exists a canonical unitary $U$ acting on
the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_\omega$ such that
$$\varphi(a)=\langle\pi_\omega(a)U^*\xi_\omega, U^*\xi_\omega\rangle$$ for all $a\in\mathfrak{A}$ (here $\langle\cdot,\cdot \rangle$ denotes the hermitian product of $\mathcal{H}_\omega)$. If in addition we suppose that $\varphi$ is invariant under the modular flow of $\omega$, then by Corollary 3.6 of Takesaki's Theory of Operator Algebras II, there exists a (possibly unbounded) positive operator $H$ affiliated with the centralizer of $\omega$ such that
$$\varphi(a)=\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow 0}\langle H_\varepsilon^\frac{1}{2}\pi_\omega(a) H_\varepsilon^\frac{1}{2}\xi_\omega,\xi_\omega\rangle$$ for all $a\in\mathfrak{A}$, where $H_\varepsilon$ is the bounded operator defined by $H_\varepsilon:= H(1+\varepsilon H)^{−1}$.
$$$$

My question is whether these hypotheses are sufficient to say that the GNS vector $\xi_\omega$ must lie in the domain $D(H^\frac{1}{2})$ of $H^\frac{1}{2}$ and that this domain is invariant under the action of $\mathfrak{A}$, namely that $\pi_\omega(\mathfrak{A})D(H^\frac{1}{2})\subseteq D(H^\frac{1}{2})$. Of course, this is exactly what happens when $\mathfrak{A}$ is a commutative $C^*$-algebra.